# Как настроить кодировку?

Tags: php, csv

Делаю перебор csv файла, с последующей записью данных построчно в базу. В процессе работы полетела кодировка и теперь у меня выводится '��N�0E�H�C�-Jܲ@5��*Q>�ēƪc[�ii����B�' вместо данных. Как можно исправить этот момент? Если нужно, вот мой код:

```
<?php

 ini_set("max_execution_time", 0); 

  header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

  require_once 'db.php';

  // подключаемся к серверу
  $link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database) or die("Ошибка " . mysqli_error($link));

  $file = $_POST['file'];
  $csv_lines  = file("book.csv");
  if(is_array($csv_lines))
  {

  $cnt = count($csv_lines);
  for($i = 0; $i < $cnt; $i++)
  {
$line = $csv_lines[$i];
$line = trim($line);

$first_char = true;

$col_num = 0;
$length = strlen($line);
for($b = 0; $b < $length; $b++)
{

  if($skip_char != true)
  {


    $process = true;

    if($first_char == true)
    {
      if($line[$b] == '"')
      {
        $terminator = '";';
        $process = false;
      }
      else
        $terminator = ';';
      $first_char = false;
    }


    if($line[$b] == '"')
    {
      $next_char = $line[$b + 1];

      if($next_char == '"')
        $skip_char = true;

      elseif($next_char == ';')
      {
        if($terminator == '";')
        {
          $first_char = true;
          $process = false;
          $skip_char = true;
        }
      }
    }


    if($process == true)
    {
      if($line[$b] == ';')
      {
       if($terminator == ';')
       {

        $first_char = true;
        $process = false;
      }
    }
  }

  if($process == true)
    $column .= $line[$b];

  if($b == ($length - 1))
  {
    $first_char = true;
  }

  if($first_char == true)
  {

    $values[$i][$col_num] = $column;
    $column = '';
    $col_num++;
  }
}
else
  $skip_char = false;
 }
 }
 }

 foreach ($values as $key => $value) {

 // записываем в базу

  $query = "INSERT INTO csv_parse (code, category, name, price, gold_price, old_price, 
  product_availability, manufacturer, barcode, product_link, img_link, update_date, region) VALUES 
  ('".$value[0]."', '".$value[1]."', '".$value[2]."', '".$value[3]."', '".$value[4]."', 
   '".$value[5]."', '".$value[6]."', '".$value[7]."', '".$value[8]."', '".$value[9]."', 
   '".$value[10]."', '".$value[11]."', '".$value[12]."')";

   $result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die("Ошибка " . mysqli_error($link));

   }

   // закрываем подключение
   mysqli_close($link);

  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ну.. возможно костыль, но решил вопрос таким образом - берется с нуля созданный чистый ms excel файл, далее заполняется нужными данными, далее "сохранить как" - "csv разделители-запятые", далее csv файл открывается в notepad++, в меню выбирается "Кодировки" - "Преобразовать в UFT-8 без BOM".

Comment: Или в скрипте при подключении к БД сообщить, какую вы устанавливаете кодировкой читать про `mysql_query("SET NAMES 'cp1251'");`